# How can i fix this syntax error in python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
a='1,4,6,7-9,10,12-15'
print(*[j for i in a.split(",") if "-" in i for j in range(int(i.split("- 
")[0]),(int(i.split("-")[1])+1)) else i])
```

*Syntax error at else part*

Comment: What is this supposed to do?  Why are `i` and `j` being used to mean different things in different places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The else clause is not available there by itself, but you don't need it:

- you can feed each comma separated section to a range, and if the numbers are consecutive there will be only number in the result, so this works for non-range values
- you can use a negative offset to get the second number from a non-range

```
print(
    *[
        j
        for i in a.split(",")
        for j in range(int(i.split("-")[0]),(int(i.split("-")[-1])+1))
    ]
)
```

Output:

```
1 4 6 7 8 9 10 12 13 14 15
```